# A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to view Grid into PDF, Select row per Id
Here is the Error I am getting

[image]

Here id my code in my Models

```
namespace Clinlab.Web.Models {
    public class RequisitionModels {

        public int ReqId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string AccountDate { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string INSCD1 { get; set; }
        public string INSINO1 { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string FaxNo { get; set; }
        public string DocNo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

here my Code in my Controller.

```
public FileStreamResult GetPdf(int? id  ) {

            Requisition all = null;
            using (ClinlabEntities dc = new ClinlabEntities()) {
                all = dc.Requisitions.FirstOrDefault(ReqId => ReqId.ReqId == id);
            }

            WebGrid grid = new WebGrid();// (source: all, canPage: false, canSort: false);
            string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("FirstName", ""),
            grid.Column("LastName", " "),
            //grid.Column("AccountNo", ""),
            grid.Column("Address", ""),
            grid.Column("City", ""),
            grid.Column("State", ""),
            grid.Column("Zip", "")

            )).ToString();

            string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{1}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table(border-spacing:10px; border-collapse:seperate;)</style>", gridHtml);
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
            using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
                var output = new MemoryStream();
                var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 15, 0, 0, -15);
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                writer.CloseStream = false;
                document.Open();
                var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);
                document.Close();
                output.Position = 0;
                return new FileStreamResult(output, "Application/Pdf");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text instead of an image of the text.